# setTitleTextAttributes not working with NSForegroundColorAttributeName

Tags: uitabbarcontroller, xcode7, uitabbar, uitabbaritem

Here is what I am doing in my `AppDelegate`

```
self.tabBarController.delegate = self;
NSDictionary *unSelectedAttributes = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                  [Utility primaryColor], NSForegroundColorAttributeName,  nil];
NSDictionary *selectedAttributes = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                      [UIColor whiteColor], NSForegroundColorAttributeName, nil];


[[UITabBarItem appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:unSelectedAttributes
                                         forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[[UITabBarItem appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:selectedAttributes
                                         forState:UIControlStateSelected];
```

and here is my firstViewController :

```
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setBarTintColor:[Utility primaryColor]];
[[UITabBar appearance] setTintColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
UITabBar * tabBar = self.tabBarController.tabBar;
UIImage *tabImage = [UIHelper makeImageWithSizeAndColor:[Utility primaryColor] : CGSizeMake(tabBar.frame.size.width/2, tabBar.frame.size.height)];
tabImage = [tabImage imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal];
tabBar.selectionIndicatorImage = [UIHelper makeImageWithSizeAndColor:[Utility primaryColor] : CGSizeMake(tabBar.frame.size.width/tabBar.items.count, tabBar.frame.size.height)];
```

my tabs are changing color but the text remains white and gray. It's not changing color as per `setTitleTextAttributes`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code for changing text color.

```
  [[UITabBarItem appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                                           [UIColor whiteColor], UITextAttributeTextColor,
                                                           nil] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        UIColor *titleHighlightedColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:153/255.0 green:192/255.0 blue:48/255.0 alpha:1.0];
        [[UITabBarItem appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                                           titleHighlightedColor, UITextAttributeTextColor,
                                                           nil] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
```

Okay its deprecated .. You can try this code

```
   [[UITabBarItem appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:@{ NSForegroundColorAttributeName : [UIColor blackColor] }
                                             forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [[UITabBarItem appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:@{ NSForegroundColorAttributeName : [UIColor redColor] }
                                             forState:UIControlStateSelected];
```

I tried your code also, thats also working fine.

```
  NSDictionary *unSelectedAttributes = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                          [UIColor blackColor], NSForegroundColorAttributeName,  nil];

    NSDictionary *selectedAttributes = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                        [UIColor redColor], NSForegroundColorAttributeName, nil];


    [[UITabBarItem appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:unSelectedAttributes
                                             forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [[UITabBarItem appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:selectedAttributes
                                             forState:UIControlStateSelected];
```

Comment: I think `UITextAttributeTextColor ` was deprecated. But, sure I will give it a try.

Comment: Thats same as what I am doing. Tried it anyway, doesn't work

Comment: Maybe I am missing something ? That's the puzzle. It's supposed to work but Its not working.

Comment: Yeah. Check once properly.

Comment: that was my question, why is it not working, I wouldn't have posted her without checking and trying multiple things.